# Owlcarousel 2 less then 2 items resize

Tags: html, css, owl-carousel

I'm using Owlcarousel 2 (ngx-owl-carousel-o) and work good till i have 4/5 box image, but if i receive only one item or two the box with the image come too big, how i can fix this problem?

attach the image where up you can see the box image as single item, too big,
and below you can see with 5 items the size it's ok.[image: attach the image where up you can see the box image as single item, too big, and below you can see with 5 items the size it's ok]

**example** http://betoffice.it
click in the button ALL under search

My Scss file

```
.content-carousel 
{
        max-width: 85vw !important;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0 0 1.5rem;

        &.category-na {

            .owl-carousel .owl-item {
                width: 100% !important;
            }
        }

        .category-title {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;

            h2 {
                padding-left: 10px;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                font-size: 16px;
            }

            a{
                margin-right: 10px;
            }
        }

        .single-item {
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
            border-radius: 3px;

            .box-img {
                position: relative;

                &::after {
                    content:'';
                    position: absolute;
                    @include bg-icon('play', center, contain, 'png');
                    width: 47px;
                    height: 47px;
                    transition: opacity .8s ease-in-out;
                    opacity: 0;
                    z-index: 10;
                    left: 0;
                    right: 0;
                    top: 0;
                    bottom: 0;
                    margin: auto;
                }
  
                &::before {
                    content:'';
                    position: absolute;
                    background-color: rgba(1,20,48,.5);
                    z-index: 9;
                    opacity: 0;
                    transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    top: 0;
                    bottom: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    right: 0;
                }
  
                &:hover {
                    
                    &::before {                          
                        opacity: 1;
                        border-top-right-radius: 3px;
                        border-top-left-radius: 3px;
                    }
  
                    &::after {                          
                        opacity: 1;
                    }

                    .date-start {
                        opacity: 0;
                    }
                }

                img {
                    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
                    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
                }
            }

            .box-meeting-info {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                flex-grow: 1;

                p{
                    color: #1a1a1a;

                    &:hover, &:focus {
                        color: #1a1a1a;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        .owl-carousel {
            
            .owl-item {
                padding: 0 10px;
            }
        }
    }

    @include media-breakpoint-up(xxl){

        .content-carousel {
            padding: 0 3rem 1.5rem;
        }
    }

owl-carousel-o {

    .single-item {
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        
        .box-meeting-info {
            position: relative;
            padding: 1em;
        }

        &:hover {
            box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        }
    }

    .owl-carousel {

        .content-link-video {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .owl-stage {
            display: flex;
            padding-bottom: 15px;
        }
    }

    .owl-theme .owl-nav {
        position: absolute;
        top: 30%;
        width: 100%;
        display: none;

        .owl-prev, .owl-next {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            background-color: #f0f0f0;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            border-radius: 1px;

            &:hover {
                background-color: #e0dede;
            }

            &::before {
                content:'';
                height: 12px;
                width: 26px;
                opacity: 0.5;
            }
        }

        .owl-prev {
            left: -50px;
            position: absolute;

            &::before {
                @include bg-icon('arrow-left', center, contain, 'png');
            }
        }

        .owl-next {
            right: -50px;
            position: absolute;
           
            &::before{
                @include bg-icon('arrow-right', center, contain, 'png');
            }
        }
    }

    @include media-breakpoint-up(xl) { 

        .owl-theme .owl-nav {
            display: block;
        }
    }
}
```

Component.html

```
    component.html

    <div class="carousel-container">
    <div class="content-carousel">
        <div class="category-title">
            <h2>Meetings</h2>
            <!--<a *ngIf="item.children.length >= 10" (click)="seeAllData(item.title)" class="btn b-button" [textContent]="'View More'"></a>-->
        </div>
        <owl-carousel-o [options]="customOptions">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let item of uniqueMeetings; let i = index">
                <ng-template carouselSlide [id]="i">
                    <a class="content-link-video" (click)="navigateTo(item._source.session_WIPOs2tId)">
                    <div class="single-item">
                        <div class="box-img">
                            <img [lazyLoad]="item._source.session_thumbnail" [defaultImage]="defaultImage" alt=""/>

                            <div class="date-start">
                                <p>{{item._source.session_startDate | date:'dd MMM yyyy'}}<span class="separator-time"> - </span><span class="time-video">{{item._source.session_startDate | date:'H:mm:ss'}}</span></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-meeting-info">
                            <div class="box-article">
                                <p class="name-product">{{item._source.session_name}}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div></a>
                </ng-template>
            </ng-container>
        </owl-carousel-o>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you think we could be able to even start to try help you without any code, example or at he very least a single hint whatsoever?. They are geniouses guys around here (sadly not me) but I doubt any of them has "Marvel type" superpowers.

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez ok i add the code, i hope this help someone

Comment: I would go with swiperjs nowadays.

Comment: @LucaReghellin thanks for suggestion but at the moment i need to solve the problem there you can find an example http://www.betoffice.it   click in the button ALL under search